# converting from caddy to aws load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

i have some preparation on project which that converting from caddy web server to AWS Load Balancer, i have already research some things related to the case. and i'm having concern about the configuration on the caddyfile:

```
{
    admin 0.0.0.0:2020

    on_demand_tls {
        ask https://api.someapi.com/domain-checker/
    }
}
```

in here the configuration refer to api endpoint to verify the domain that listed on the service. after that the domain will ask for https / ssl certificate. because we will convert it fully to loadbalancer, how do i manage this `on_demand_tls` to make sure the load balancer domain get renewal certificate each time (since this time we're manage to use caddy with acme certificate)

notes : in some point the needs of loadbalancer i already research about using AWS lambda to renewal the certificate for each domain, perhaps is there another way to renew.

- To implement the on_demand_tls there are some way:
  https://tobilg.com/building-a-global-reverse-proxy-with-on-demand-ssl-support

  - Using lambda for automate the SSL Renew for subdomain